# With and without a comma

Tags: commas

1. I didn’t open the door when he was here.

It can mean I opened the door the other time.

2. I didn’t open the door, when he was here.

Does it mean I didn’t open the door at all and I didn’t open the door especially when he was here?

Comment: If you didn't open the door at all, why would you specify "when he was here"?

Answer (score 6):

> I didn’t open the door when he was here.

I would take this to mean "I didn't open the door **while** he was here" and you are right in saying you could have opened the door at other times.

> I didn’t open the door, when he was here.

I don't think this really makes sense. If you wanted to convey your second meaning then I think you need to say something like "I never opened the door, particularly when  he was here"

Comment: i could see using the second one to represent a kind of spoken pause, to convey something like "I didn't open the door - I mean, not when he was here."  But I agree that it doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: @stangdon If someone said (not wrote) "I didn't open the door <pause> while he was here. " then I would expect an implied continuation, spoken or not "...but I did open it before he came / after he left". Although they do mean essentially the same in this context, again **while** works better than **when** to me as a native BE speaker.